# SVG throws system exception in XAML for xamarin

Tags: c#, ios, xaml, svg, xamarin

I am builidng a XAML UI, with Xamarin.Forms, using [this](https://github.com/paulpatarinski/Xamarin.Forms.Plugins/tree/master/SVG) nuget plugin. I have followed the guide, bit due to the plugin not supporting the `Style` tag in the SVG file, I have commented this out of my SVG source. I have the following XAML Layout:

```
   <Grid VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" BackgroundColor="#3DBEAF" >
   <Grid.RowDefinitions>
       <RowDefinition Height="10" />
       <RowDefinition Height="Auto" /> 
   </Grid.RowDefinitions>
   <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="10" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  <abstractions:SvgImage Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" SvgAssembly="{Binding SvgAssembly}" SvgPath="{Binding Logo_Round}" HeightRequest="50" WidthRequest="50" BackgroundColor="White" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
   </Grid>
```

However, now when running the app, I get the following error, what is that about? Is there something I can do to work around it, or is there something I can do to further debug?

> System.Exception: Invalid parameters to context creation
>     at CoreGraphics.CGContext.set_Handle (IntPtr value) [0x00010] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2377/73229919/source/maccore/src/CoreGraphics/CGContext.cs:161
>     at CoreGraphics.CGContext..ctor (IntPtr handle, Boolean owns) [0x00006] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2377/73229919/source/maccore/src/CoreGraphics/CGContext.cs:141
>     at CoreGraphics.CGBitmapContext..ctor (IntPtr data, nint width, nint height, nint bitsPerComponent, nint bytesPerRow, CoreGraphics.CGColorSpace colorSpace, CGImageAlphaInfo bitmapInfo) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2377/73229919/source/maccore/src/CoreGraphics/CGBitmapContext.cs:62
>     at NGraphics.iOS.Custom.ApplePlatform.CreateImageCanvas (Size size, Double scale, Boolean transparency) [0x0005c] in :0
>     at SVG.Forms.Plugin.iOS.SvgImageRenderer.OnElementChanged (Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.ElementChangedEventArgs`1 e) [0x0010f] in :0

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: @valdetero I did - but I am afraid it was to move too [NativeScript](https://www.nativescript.org/) ...

Comment: Well that's disappointing. I didn't want to have to render all the pngs but I will if I can't get the svg library to work.